# WCF service: The namespace and source of the classes has been changed

Tags: c#, wcf, service, namespaces

I have solution with 3 projects:
1. Client (reference: DataContracts and ServiceReference created via Visual Studio 2012 with name TaskerWcfService)
2. DataContracts
3. WCF Service (DataContracts)

First I've created WCFService and in DataContracts was only one class:

```
[DataContract]
public class WorkItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String ItemType { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I've created a Client with a ServiceReference (with name: TaskerWcfReference) and namespace for the WorkItem class has been - DataContracts lib.
And finally, I've extended WCF Service and DataContracts with additional class:

```
public class InfoData
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Int32 Order { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

But when I've updated the ServiceReference I found that InfoData class was inside of the automatically generated proxy and it's namespace is: TaskerWcfReference.InfoData.

Why the classes described in similar way - placed in different places? 
The functions of the service contracts return Generic.List and T in same way. Descriptions of the service contracts are similar too.

Comment: Does InfoData also have a [DataContract] attribute?

Comment: @ВасилийХимченко From what I read, it sounds like you are putting data contracts in a separate project and then duplicating the class in the WCF Service project.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes of coarse [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes are defined.

Comment: I found problem/ It seems - it is such issue of the Visual Studio.

Comment: It seems - it is such issue of the Visual Studio.

Required datasource file is creating but it is not moved from ServiceReference to Data Sources folder.
To resolve problem it is enough to RESTART Visual Studio and 'Update Service Reference' again.